# error with creating new cronjob

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, whm

When I try to create new cron job in cpanel I get the error below:

> You (androido) are not allowed to use this program (/usr/bin/crontab)
>   See crontab(1) for more information

Or the following error with a different account:

> Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info You (sms)
>   are not allowed to access to (/usr/bin/crontab) because of pam
>   configuration.

I've checked and /usr/bin/crontab permission is 4755.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cpanel, but what happens if you try to add a job by running `crontab -e`?

If that works, your problem is not permission-related.

Comment: crontab -e work fine, but I need add cron tab by cpanel features

Comment: something wrong between cpanel and os. cronjob run fine but I cant add crontab by cpanel.